# How does useMemo() create an id for its factories?

Tags: reactjs, react-usememo

There is a function in React called `useMemo()`

```
const eg = React.useMemo(() => true, []);
```

If I included the same function twice, how would it know which memoization to return?

```
const eg1 = React.useMemo(() => Math.random(), []);
const eg2 = React.useMemo(() => Math.random(), []);
```

There's no explicit ID for either of these arrow functions, and -- that I know of -- there is no way to ID them except to perhaps hash their inner text.  In this case, they'd both have the same ID.

What kind of funky magic is going on here?

Comment: Also, this isn't really relevant but that's not the same function twice. That's two different functions that both take no arguments and return the result of invoking `Math.random`. `(() => 1) === (() => 1) // false`. But Nicholas' answer is 100% correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React knows which is which because it makes the assumption that you will always call `useMemo` exactly the same number of times, in exactly the same order. Thus, it knows that the 1st time you call `useMemo` during a render, it should check the dependency array from the 1st call last time, and return the 1st value. Then the second time you call `useMemo`, it checks the 2nd dependency array and returns the 2nd value. Etc.

That's why the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) insist that you can't call hooks conditionally.

Comment: Ah.  It doesn't allow for conditions.  I had wondered if that was maybe the "solution" they decided upon.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of useMemo, it just won't be able to memorize and will always recalculate the values due to lack of parameters.

useMemo avoids calculations if function parameters are the same, if there are no parameters, a new value will be calculated on each rendering.

Comment: I'm pretty sure an empty array an an empty parameter are treated differently.